# Creating rounded corner Div which has a box shadow also

Tags: html, css

**Html:**

```
<div id='base_container'>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
#base_container{ 
    width:970px; 
    margin:auto; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    background:#red; 
    border-radius:10px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

[image]

In the above code for the 'base_container', I need to create border-radius and box-shadow using images, not with css3 which is already existing. I never had gone through with this technic before and also it should be properly displayed in IE-8. One more thing is the 'base_container' height is 'auto'. I have uploaded a jpg image aslo. Please help me on this.

Comment: r u asking us to code for you? did u try anything? You have the image. slice all the corners and repeated shadows. Do the HTML. If you have any issues then post it here. we will try to help you to fix the issues.

Comment: I am already working on this...If you have better solutions please post me...I mentioned in the question I am very new for this technic.

Comment: u started working right? that is want we want to know. what you tried? so that we can give our suggestion.

Comment: Why bother with all that effort just to give IE8 rounded corners? IE8 users can live with square corners and everyone benefits with leaner code and fewer images.

Comment: you could use http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HAC4L/)

```
 <div class="square-box">
 <div class="top"></div>
 <div class="content">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In id dapibus ante. Quisque et mi felis. Mauris sollicitudin, nulla nec rutrum posuere, augue risus ultricies tortor, eu posuere velit ligula ac ipsum. Mauris tellus sem, egestas ac venenatis eu, ultricies in urna. Morbi eget faucibus justo. Cras egestas adipiscing felis, at commodo urna ultrices pulvinar. Cras iaculis, sem sit amet tincidunt adipiscing, orci orci tincidunt velit, a pellentesque sapien mauris vel est. Sed semper scelerisque ligula, in viverra risus lobortis quis. Sed sed feugiat nulla. Aenean dignissim dolor eget nibh mattis, quis mattis eros ultrices. Sed hendrerit vel lorem vel gravida. Cras neque urna, egestas eu varius id, tempor sit amet magna. Aenean consequat porttitor ante, vel dictum tortor tristique a. Cras in purus sed nisl lacinia pulvinar.

 Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nunc non vehicula ligula. Pellentesque fringilla sem non eros interdum, id venenatis enim condimentum. Nam ac suscipit libero. Nullam ultrices, felis eu placerat euismod, erat est posuere lacus, quis volutpat eros velit sit amet mi. Aliquam libero erat, aliquam in fringilla quis, egestas interdum lorem. Nunc at lobortis tellus. Aenean lorem urna, bibendum eu faucibus id, tincidunt non est.
 </div>
 <div class="bottom"></div>
 </div>

 .square-box{width:600px;}
 .square-box .top{background:url('http://i.imgur.com/KRjgdhP.jpg') no-repeat 0 0; height:27px; float:left; width:100%;}
 .square-box .content{background:url('http://i.imgur.com/zjNrRfD.jpg') repeat-y 0 0; min-height:100px; padding:0 5%;  float:left; width:90%;}
 .square-box .bottom{background:url('http://i.imgur.com/mOXsXSQ.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;  height:27px;  float:left; width:100%;}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want...could you please let me know how many images u sliced...

Comment: Just 3 images top image, content background and the bottom image. If you feel this is the solution then upvote it so others can use it also

Comment: see the css you can see the url http://i.imgur.com/KRjgdhP.jpg, http://i.imgur.com/zjNrRfD.jpg, http://i.imgur.com/mOXsXSQ.jpg

Comment: why I am asking is, I just need clarification mainly regarding slicing of images...like you said'top image' means, u taken entire top part vertically or horizontally or only corners???

Comment: Thanks San...thanks a lot...I will let you know once I implement it. Once its working for me...I will definitely vote.

Comment: entire top horizontally with height of 27 px same for the bottom

Answer (score 3):

you can make a rounded corner and create a shadow using power of CSS3. ofcourse it not accurate as posted image, you have to play a bit with color and shadow dimensions.

If you are supporting older browsers you have to use a vendor prefix for firefox and IE

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pozeqequ/1/edit)**.

> **Note:** If you are supporting older browser like IE7 and IE8 you can use `Modernizr` which is a JavaScript library that detects HTML5 and
>   CSS3.

```
.shadow {
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  border-radius:4%; /*supported by all latest Browser*/
  -moz-border-radius:4%; /*For older Browser*/
  -webkit-border-radius:4%;/*For older Browser*/
  background-color:red;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

Comment: OP -> 'it should be properly displayed in IE-8'

Comment: hi Pandey...I have to do it only with images...not css3 which I already know.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why use css image because there is practical and cross-browser solution

for example

**css**

```
div.shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #444;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #444;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#444444')";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#444444');
}

.round {
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 

  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
  -moz-border-radius: 12px; 

  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
  border-radius: 12px; 
  behavior: url(http://yoursite.com/border-radius.htc);
}
```

Comment: sorry i yeah forgot to add .round {  
 behavior: url(http://yoursite.com/border-radius.htc);  
}

Comment: <!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" /><![endif]-->

Comment: I am not allowed to use any hacks.

Comment: this solution its works
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
background: #EEFF99;
behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);

Comment: if not allowed not to use hacks that support comes from IE9 +

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (old) way to do this for old browsers is take this your image into photoshop,

- slice all the corners including the shadow, the radius and some of
  the inner color.. make sure they are the same size..
- slice the top, right, left and bottom shadows, make sure each shadow
  is the height or width as the corresponding corners..(example: left
  shadow would be the same width as the top left and    bottom left
  corners)

Make an HTML TABLE:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="topleftcorner" /></td>
        <td style='background:url(img/topshadow.png) repeat-x 0 0'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><img src="toprightcorner" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style='background:url(img/leftshadow.png) repeat-y 0 0'></td>
        <td class='content'>HERE GOES THE CONTENT OF THE BOX</td>
        <td style='background:url(img/rightshadow.png) repeat-y 0 0'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="bottomleftcorner" /></td>
        <td style='background:url(img/bottomshadow.png) repeat-x 0 0'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><img src="bottomrightcorner" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

of course then you would need to style the widths and heights accordingly.
.content would have the background color of the boxes inner color..